# add class to a div when hover another one (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a limited understanding of Javascriptan I am trying to add a class to a div when I hover another div
Right now I can add a class to the same div but I would like to be able to add let's say the class blue to a div called first when I hover #second and #third.

current code :

```
    
    $(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#second, #third").hover(function(){     
    $(this).addClass("hover");    
    $(this).removeClass("hoverable");      
    },     
    function(){    
    $(this).removeClass("hover");     
        $(this).addClass("hoverable");     
    }  
    );     
    });
```

My live website can be seen at : www.designinterieurm2.com/dev

Comment: This will possibly include DOM traversal of some kind, what does the relevant html look like?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#second, #third').hover(function(){     
        $('#first').addClass('blue');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('#first').removeClass('blue');     
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked! The mistake I was making was using double quotes instead of single quotes inside my function

Comment: No, sorry, that was not the problem. Double or single quotes both work, as long as the overall syntax is correct you can use either. I actually prefer single quotes, and will eliminate double-quotes when I notice them.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `$(this)` with `$("#div_id");`

where `#div_id` is the id of the div you're trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".toptab").hover(function(){

    $(this).addClass("current");
    $(this).find("ul").show();

},function(){

    $(this).find("ul").hide();
    $(this).removeClass("current");

});
```